# How to transfer a cart to <BrowserFromPost> in PHP (cxml Punch-out Order Message)

Tags: php

I've been learning cxml for the past two weeks. At first it’s horrible. But eventually it gets easier. So I was finally able to successfully use a Punch-out Setup Request which will return the start <StartPage> URL. I can browse the supplier website and add to the cart.

Now I need to transfer the items in the cart to my page. In the  Punch-out Setup Request I had to provide the URL for that <BrowserFormPost> URL. When I click on the transfer cart, the supplier website will redirect me to mypage. Now how do I parse or even get the Punch-out Order Message in PHP.

Here is how the punchoutordermessage should look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.014/cXML.dtd">
<cXML timestamp="2019-05-04T13:44:46+00:00" xml:lang="en-US" payloadID="zxysdfdsdafasdfsfdsf">
    <Header>
        <From>
            <Credential domain='NetworkID'>
                <Identity></Identity>
            </Credential>
        </From>
        <To>
            <Credential domain='NetworkID'>
                <Identity></Identity>
            </Credential>
        </To>
        <Sender>
            <Credential domain='NetworkID'>
                <Identity></Identity>
                <SharedSecret></SharedSecret>
            </Credential>
            <UserAgent></UserAgent>
        </Sender>
    </Header>

    <Message>
        <Punch-outOrderMessage>
            <BuyerCookie></BuyerCookie>
            <Punch-outOrderMessageHeader operationAllowed="edit">
                <Total>
                    <Money currency="USD">300.52</Money>
                </Total>
            </Punch-outOrderMessageHeader>
            <ItemIn quantity="1">
                <ItemID>
                <SupplierPartID></SupplierPartID>
                <SupplierPartAuxiliaryID></SupplierPartAuxiliaryID>
                </ItemID>
                <ItemDetail>
                    <UnitPrice>
                        <Money currency="USD">7.99</Money>
                    </UnitPrice>
                    <Description xml:lang="en"></Description>
                    <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>

                </ItemDetail>
            </ItemIn>

        </Punch-outOrderMessage>
    </Message>
</cXML>
```

I've tried using the *simplexml_load_file*. No help. I'm not sure what exactly happens when the buyer clicks on the transfer cart besides it will load the page that I supplied.

There is not much information out there about cxml. It’s been really hard to get any information.

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("cxml_form") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    print_r($xml);
?>
```

PHP

Answer (score 0):

When the customer clicks on checkout/transfercart, the supplier site sends the message to your page. However, in order to receive it, you must automatically post the form.

On your <BrowseFromPost> page: add the following PHP code:

```php
<?php $xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $URL = "https://yourlandingpage";

    echo "<FORM ID='xmlpostform' METHOD=POST ACTION='" . $URL . "'>";
    echo "<INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME='cXML-urlencoded' VALUE='" . $xml . "'>";
    echo "<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE='Sending Order Information...'>";
    echo "</FORM>";
?>
```

```html
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">document.forms["xmlpostform"].submit();</SCRIPT>
```

To retrieve the value using VB.NET:

```vbnet
Dim cxml As String = doc.GetElementById("cXML-urlencoded").GetAttribute("VALUE")
```